# How to Launch the SoftKey When Activity Started in android

Tags: android

i want to launch the  SoftKeyBoard when activity launch. i tried this code it is working
 for the potrait mode but it is not working in landscape mode can any one help me to do that
 thanks in advance.

```
      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

do you have a layout-land folder in your workspace? If not, create one and add the xml from the layout folder with the same name. Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Rashmi Thanks for your reply it is working now with my prevoius code itself without changing. just i changed the settings in my device.